# audio program killed by ALSA

Tags: sound, alsa

My Waveform audio program initializes and then dies.

```
ALSA lib pcm.c:8432:(snd_pcm_recover) underrun occurred
ALSA lib pcm.c:8432:(snd_pcm_recover) underrun occurred
ALSA lib pcm.c:8432:(snd_pcm_recover) underrun occurred
```

Killed.
Anyone knows why ALSA is killing the program and how I might stop it?

Comment: You haven't given any OS/release details;

Comment: The ALSA library does not deliberately kill the program. It's possible that these messages have nothing to do with the problem. Does "my waveform audio program" imply that you have written it yourself? In that case, keeping the source secret is not helpful.

Comment: The program is Waveform 9 64bit Linux. Running Ubuntu Studio v19.